# Whats the correct way of using media queries

Tags: css

What is the correct way of using media queries.

Is it method

#### A.)

```
@media (max-width: 992px){
  something here
}
```

Or method

#### B.)

```
@media (min-width: 442px) and (max-width: 992px)
```

Comment: Why one of this can be incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Both your examples are valid, but they are different.

`@media (max-width: 992px){` The screen is narrower than 992px.

`@media (min-width: 442px) and (max-width: 992px){` The screen is wider than 442px, **and** narrower than 992px.